# Axiom of Choice and fullness of the class of terms of the forcing language

Tags: logic, set-theory, axiom-of-choice, forcing

It is well-known that when doing forcing over some ground model $M$, if we assume the Axiom of Choice in $M$, then the class of terms of the language of forcing has the property that for any $p \in \mathbb{P}$, if $$p \Vdash_{\mathbb{P}} \exists x \varphi(x),$$
then there exists a term $\tau \in M^\mathbb{P}$ such that 
$$p \Vdash_{\mathbb{P}} \varphi(\tau).$$

It is often underlined that this maximality property (that the class of names is full in the sense above) is actually crucial for many arguments.

My questions are as follows:

(1) can you please give examples of theorems in the theory of forcing that would not hold if the class of names was not full (so I do not mean the ones in the proofs of which this property just appears, but the ones in which it is indeed essentially used)?

(2) if we drop the assumption of AC in the ground model, how much of the properties from the reply to (1) can we keep/recover (and what kind of forms of weak AC would be necessary then)?

(3) how do you prove that if $M \not\models AC$, then fullness does not hold?

Comment: For (3), see problem 1.30 (page 36) in Bell's *Set Theory: Boolean-Valued Models and Independence Proofs*, Third Edition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing about fullness is that it is *very* convenient. It allows you to reason about "future objects" from "the present". In other words, it lets you talk about a [name for an] element of a set $\dot A$, if you know that it is not empty.

But the machinery of forcing is set up such that you can avoid doing that. $p\Vdash\dot A\neq\varnothing$, then there is some $q<p$ and some $\dot a$ such that $q\Vdash\dot a\in\dot A$. So by extending $p$, we can seemingly overcome this problem.

When does fullness *really* play a significant role then? When we need to make infinitely many choices, of course. Because if we can continue choosing without having to worry about extending the condition $p$, then we don't run into closure properties or chain conditions, which are combinatorially more complicated.

As for actual examples? None come to mind. In the absence of choice forcing is more complicated because closure properties and chain conditions no longer have the same influence as they did in $\sf ZFC$. Of course, we normally use these properties to prove fullness to begin with, so that makes sense.

Iterated forcing becomes more of a nuisance, because anything which is not a finite-support iteration is using fullness in a very fundamental way. We can still overcome this quite easily, and then the problem become *choosing* the sequences for the names at limit steps, which is where choice *really* plays a role.

---

Finally, to see why fullness implies choice, go back to the very first paragraph. If $A=\{A_i\mid i\in I\}$ is a family of pairwise disjoint non-empty sets, define $\Bbb P=\{A\}\cup A$, and $q<p\leftrightarrow q\in p$.

Now consider $\dot X$ to be the name $\{(A_i,\check a)\mid a\in A_i, i\in I\}$, in other words each $A_i$ forces that $\dot X$ is $A_i$ itself. We have that $A$, which is the maximum condition of $\Bbb P$, forces $\dot X\neq\varnothing$, that is to say, $\exists x(x\in\dot X)$. By fullness there is a name $\dot x$ such that $A\Vdash\dot x\in\dot X$. But now each $A_i$ must interpret $\dot x$ as one of its own elements, which is a choice function.

Comment: I have a question regarding your final paragraph: your definition of $\dot{X}$ is fixed on some $I$, right? Doesn't that imply that $A_i \Vdash \dot{X} = \check{A_i}$ but $A_j \Vdash \dot{X} = \emptyset$ for any $i \neq j$ (since $A_I \cap A_j$ is empty)? Where am I going wrong? (And I assume by $q < p$ you mean the usual "$q$ is stronger than $p$", right?)

Comment: No, each $A_i$ would interpret $\dot X$ to be itself. I suppose it's another typo, I forgot to quantify the $i$... that's what it's like to write an answer straight out of bed.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying, thank you for that! A follow-up has arisen: what exactly is the choice function? I don't see how $\dot{x}$ interpreted by any generic filter will be a function at all.

Comment: Well, $F(A_i)=a$ if and only if $A_i\Vdash\dot x=\check a$. It's a name, it's a concrete object in the ground model.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, using definability of the forcing relation. Thank you!

Comment: @Asaf: " that's what it's like to write an answer straight out of bed." - I knew you would do that with a question on the AC in the context of forcing! Thanks for the answer, it's very helpful!

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have another question: any dense set contains some $A_i$, right? So if $M$ (ctm as usual) contains two dense sets of $\mathbb{P}$ containing $A_0$ and $A_1$ respectively, say, doesn't that mean that $M[G] \vDash \dot{x}[G] \in A_0 \land \dot{x}[G] \in A_1$, which should be a contradiction?

Comment: @MacRance: No, *every* dense set has to include *all* of the $A_i$'s. In fact, there are only two dense sets: $\Bbb P$ and $A$ itself. Every generic filter is just choosing a single $A_i$.